Why does a new folder inside C:\ inherit permissions that C:\ doesn't actually have?
I just created a new folder inside C:\ called "test".
Checking it's DACL reveals that the group "Authenticated Users" has every permission on it except for Full Control and Special Permissions.
A picture of the permissions
However, when I check where it got these permissions from, it says it inherited these permissions from C:\
But as we know, Authenticated Users doesn't have modify permissions on C:\, so how could it have inherited it?

When you look at the Advanced Security Settings for the top-level C:\ drive, there is an entry to allow Authenticated Users to have Modify access to Subfolders and files only:


So how come folders inside C:\ don't just inherit that as-is and allow new folders to modify subfolders and files only?

@Skity That entry gives Modify permissions to subfolders of C:\ . When you look at the inherited rule on C:\test, it shows as applying to "This folder, subfolders and files", right? Basically, the Modify permission is inheritable, but doesn't apply to C:\ itself - that's just how it's displayed in the interface

@Cpt.Whale i think hes missing how group is applied to user once user clicks on folder(anywhere).
